# Bukkit help "identifier expected"

Tags: bukkit

here is the code

```
package agam.play;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.CreatureSpawnEvent;

public class Listeners implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void creatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent) {

    }
}
```

here is the error

```
Error:(10,49) java: <identifier> expected
```

I would appreciate some help
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires you to name all of a function's arguments, even if you don't use them. Change `public void creatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent) {` to `public void creatureSpawn(CreatureSpawnEvent event) {`.